# Wordpress template assignment not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

Whilst risking duplicating another post, I think this may be unique as other similar posts I've read haven't given me an answer that works for me. I have spent hours going through answers in other posts to no avail. I feel like what I've done should be working, but for some reason isn't.

I am new to Wordpress (but not development in general), and have set up a custom theme and page template (called index-gallery.php based on index.php and modified slightly to pull out my custom gallery posts). I have assigned that template using the page template dropdown on the right hand side of the page edit screen (using the remarked template name 'gallery page' that shows up fine in the list). So, you'd expect that to over-ride the standard hierarchy settings. However it isn't being applied and I'm seeing the index.php template being used. However, if I change the parent page of my 'gallery' page to be the home page it suddenly uses the 'index-gallery.php' template and the template works exactly as I'd expect. So I know it's not an issue with the template itself, as it works in that instance. I'm using 'what the file' plugin to see what templates are being used. I've tried re-assigning the slug in the page edit and re-setting permalinks etc, but that hasn't solved it.

Does anyone know what may be getting in the way of the template assignment when it's not parented to the home page? I don't really want it parented in that way.

This is all set up on my localhost running on xampp using Wordpress 4.9.7

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your template files to something else (that doesn't begin with one of the standard WP template file names) - such as **template-gallery.php**

Oh, and you might find it better to base page templates on the **page.php** file anyway.

Comment: I did originally have it called page-gallery.php as it happens, because I followed a tutorial that told me to do that. That was before I started problem solving and started the whole thing based off of the index.php page. Then I called it template-gallery.php. So already been there and that made no difference at all. I do think it's something I've done, being a noob at WordPress but can't quite work out what it is. I do find the way WordPress does that automated template locating a bit weird - much prefer a more specified way of working.

Comment: Ok, so the difference between parented and not parented page seems to be the slug that gets generated. When I parent the gallery page the slug I see is 'http://localhost/wordpress/custom-posts-page/gallery/' whereas when I don't parent it I just get 'http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/'. What I don't quite understand is where the custom-posts-page bit is coming from and how that affects the template choice.

Comment: Sorry, I know this doesn't help, but I've never had a problem like that. Pages in all of my sites have always used their assigned templates, no matter how deep in a page hierarchy they are! Perhaps it's a plugin or theme conflict. Try it with all plugins turned off and see what happens. Then try a child theme of one of the standard WP themes with just your template.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Ultimately, I think I may have broken something in my dabblings! It certainly doesn't seem to be behaving as the documentation would suggest. I may have to start my theme again from scratch - I've tried truning off all the plugins to no avail. There aren't many anyway as this is just a test site for me to learn to theme with, although I'm using it to build an IE7 friendly (don't ask!) version of our main website.